# How to create user with only SSH permissions

Tags: ssh, account-restrictions

I need to create a user which can SSH to a server, but can not run any commands or view anything, for the purposes of tunneling the connection without risk of revealing credentials. How do I do this? I looked on google but found no sources.

Edit: Would it also be possible to show a certain message to the user upon login? Instead of the usual 'Last logged in from xxx at yyy'?

Comment: @HalosGhost - tunneling. Author mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sleepshell http://www.mariovaldez.net/software/sleepshell/ or
rbash http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell
could be you need.